# compiling and deploy window mobile phone platform games into xbox360 game platform with XNA 4.0

Tags: xna-4.0, xbox360

I am developing game for Xbox 360 and I am very new to this game development area. But it seems like attaching with the console and testing games takes time. So, I plan to develop my game with `Window Phone Platform` , so I can test easily with `emulator`.

1) Is there any way that I can compile my `Window platform games` into `Xbox360 game platform`  after I finish my development?

2) How can I perform this steps in `Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate`?

3) Which one is easier and convenient?

- Developed in `Window Platform` and convert into `Xbox 360 Platform`
- Developed in `Mobile Phone Platform` and convert into `Xbox 360 Platform`

Any guides, or resources will be much helpful for me.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(FWIW My usual path is to create a Windows version first followed by Phone and Xbox 360 as the run / deployment turn around time for Windows is the fastest out of the three)

This is achieved within Visual Studio through the "Create ... copy" option supplied by the XNA portion of the SDK when one right clicks on a project within the solution explorer.

In terms of ease, I suspect going from Mobile to XBox 360 is probably the path of least pain as you're going from the most restrictive environment to a less restrictive (and more powerful) environment so things have the best chance of getting better rather than worse in the transition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and simple answer. Could you please elaborate more about steps that I have to follow on deploying of converted window to phone(xbox) platform? any restrictions?

Comment: Deployment to the Xbox 360 consists of downloading and installing the XNA Game Connector ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975643.aspx ) and then it's the normal deploy / run / debug cycle of Visual Studio.


The technical restrictions are less restrictive than mobile so you shouldn't run into any issues on that front.